# How can I sort Doctrine query by the number of members of a relation?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a class with one-to-many relation and I want to retrieve the entities sorted by the number of members of the relation.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645897/how-to-sort-a-doctrine-dql-query-by-the-number-or-members-of-a-relation) I have partly found a solution. But **the problem is that I only get the first entity in the result.** Any help much appreciated!
Here is the code:

```
//from the AdminCause.php
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Vote", mappedBy="cause")
 */
protected $votes;

//the corresponding repository
class AdminCauseRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByVotesNumber()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
          ->createQuery('SELECT x, COUNT(v) as HIDDEN votes FROM AreweUserBundle:AdminCause x LEFT JOIN x.votes v ORDER BY votes')
          ->getResult();
    }
}

//and them call it in the controller
$causes = $em->getRepository('AreweUserBundle:AdminCause')->findAllOrderedByVotesNumber();
```